Setting Up NAT Port Forwarding and Nginx on Mini PC with Ubuntu Server 24.04
I have a mini PC on that pc I want to run my dynamic web application.
I am trying to do the following things

install host ubuntu server LTS 24.04
install guest Ubuntu server LTS 24.04 using kvm/qemu
do NAT  port forwarding setting on host OS to guest OS like when I access host IP 192.168.100.1 and port 22 this should SSH to a guest OS and when I use port 50022 this should connect the host OS
after that I am planning to install the nginx web service for running my web application
after that copy my web application file to the guest OS then run it on mini pc

final output going to be when I access on internet as the host IP address my web application should run
BUT: i got stuck on point 3

Are you using a virtual machine app? If not how is the guest computer connected to the host computer? Are they both concerned to the Dave Wi-Fi? Edit your question and add these information.

@user68186 I am using kvm/qemu for virtualization. and both are on the same network
